# Function defination meaning in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the following function definition mean in JavaScript:

```js
var Candy = (function(self, $) {
    return self;
}  (Candy || {}, jQuery));
```

I am still learning JavaScript. And am trying to read and understand one of the applications I downloaded online. I can't figure out what the meaning of the above function definition is. This is only the trimmed version of the module.

Comment: where did you find this?

Comment: This is an immediately invoked function expression.

Comment: i need the explanation. yes its an immediately invoked but i dont understand what is goin on here

Comment: It's a namespacing pattern ([see section 4 of this article](https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/)).